# Call Postgres function from Spring Data Jpa which return non-entity response

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement Postgres function call from Spring data.

Function receives json and returns json which I would like to map onto object. This function also creates response from multiple tables, so I cannot map it specific Entity, next won't work :

```
@Entity(name = "myEntity")
public class MyClass {
 
   private String id;
   ...other props
}
```

Also I cannot create repository for this as such entity in db doesn't exist:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, String> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select my_func(:name)")
    String getResp(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

This also won't work.

How to call postgres function and map it to some class or at least into string, as my function returns json.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know much about spring. i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61898613/7772483) can help you

Comment: *cannot map it specific Entity* You can always say `new Foo(a, b, c)`, and if it's a plain string you can just return that.